# Can't map network drive

Tags: nas, synology

*(I asked this before on the Synology forum, but got no answer there.)*

Configuration:
- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- Synology DS213air NAS

I've connected my NAS in Synology Assistant, and I can see the File Station with its folders in my browser, so my PC can see the NAS alright. However, the NAS doesn't show up under "Network" in Windows Explorer.

I try to map network drive from within Synology Assistant. After entering my username and password I can see a message

[image]

for about 45 seconds, then

[image]

Two things I noticed:

1. When entering username and password only the username must match, I can enter whatever password (or none at all) and it is accepted. I do have a password set, because I can't log in with the wrong password.
2. I noticed the NAS sits on a completely different IP subnet than my PC. Could this be the problem? Apparently the IP address derives from the "default gateway" setting in the control panel, but it looks like I can't modify that there.

How can I make my NAS visible on my network, and map it to a drive letter (either from within Synology Assistant or Windows Explorer?

**PS:** Until a couple of days ago this connection worked without problems. But then I got a message out of the blue that I was connected to "network 6". Might this unasked-for change in network connection have changed some settings? What do I have to look for then?

**update** following *Big Chris'* comment
In the control panel there's a field "default gateway", which, according to the manual should be editable, but it isn't.

[image]

(The "edit" button next to it only lets you change the service order.) Could it be that the NAS operates as a DHCP **server** instead of **client**? How can I change that?

Comment: Did you try this with no firewall and no internet security protection? I've had many many issues with my NAS and it turned out to be firewall related (on the NAS or the PC)

Comment: @Dave - Thanks for your reply. I tried with the firewall of, no avail. BTW, doesn't the fact that I can access the NAS in my browser mean that it's not the firewall?

Comment: IMO no. I could get to the NAS site via browser on my machine, but not access it via Windows. You could try accessing the NAS via your mobile phone?

Comment: Are the NAS and computer on a home/small network? If so, is there a reason for the different subnets? You should be able to set the NAS to be a DHCP client so it gets the rights details from your router?

Comment: @BigChris - Yes, it's on a home network (well, the PC is, and the NAS should be). I guess the NAS operates as a DHCP *server*, not *client*. According to the manual I should be able to edit default gateway, but it's not an edit box. An edit button only lets me change service order (whatever that may be). I know about programming, but I'm not very network-savvy, and this NAS is so complex to configure that IMO complete laymen *never* can do it. If you think the gateway is the problem I'll add about that in my question. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Have a read of this forum regarding the NAS you have and how to check/disable the DHCP and connect it to your existing wifi: http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=145&t=61232 - it's a tricky one because you have to change the wireless from being a "router" (which is what it's probably doing now - i.e. it's acting as a DHCP server) and then connect it to your existing wireless but when you disable the DHCP it'll drop off your network... you may need to connect it to your wireless first and then disable the DHCP. Plus: it's all under the "Network interface" tab on your screen grab.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

The NAS was connected to a switch which in turn was directly connected to my modem (not through a router, there are historic reasons). So the IP address seems to have come directly from my ISP's DHPC server.

I changed the connections so that from the modem I now go to a wireless router. (I'm not using the NAS' wireless router since I also want wired connections from the router.)
The NAS now gets the usual 192.168.x.x IP address from the router, and I can map it to a Windows drive letter.

*(I hope this makes sense. Like I said in comment I'm not particularly network-savvy.)*

---

I still don't understand that the old setup used to work, but suddenly stopped working for no obvious reason...

Comment: It's a bit crazy that your ISP didn't provide you with a modem/router/switch all-in-one (like most ISPs do)...?!

Comment: @BigChris - Usually they do. Like I said there were historic reasons for that setup (which no longer apply). I was probably the only customer directly connected to their servers :-).